# The name 'CommerceTypeLoader' does not exist in the current context

Tags: sitecore-commerce

[image]

I merged the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\storefront\Website\MergeFiles\Merge.Commerce.Storefront.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\storefront\Website\MergeFiles\Merge.CommerceServer.config
to

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\storefront\Website\web.config

reading the Kb article but it did not fix the issue

```
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/496086
```

my web.config file is as follows

https://jsfiddle.net/rrvttc04/

Thanks
rocky

Answer (score 5):

As I see, you merged Merge.web.config to main site web.config instead of merge to views config.

> The web.config file located in the \views folder of the website root
>   directory must be merged with the merge.web.config file located in the
>   \merge\views folder of the website root directory.

For resolve this issue, you need to merge `{YourSitecoreWebsite}\MergeFiles\Views\Merge.web.config` to `{YourSitecoreWebsite}\Views\web.config`

Example of Merge.web.config, which you need to merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Data" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Data.Items" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Models" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Extensions" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Orders.Models"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Profiles.Models"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Inventory.Models"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Globalization"/>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Reference.Storefront"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <system.web>
    <pages 
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places of web.config need to be merged.

1. web.config at the main folder (web root)
2. web.config in **Views** folder (Views/web.config). I think you missed this part.

In the later place, there are some namespaces need to include to the view.

Hope it help you.